# logstash testing a configuration pipeline failing(Translation missing)

Tags: apache, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

New to logstash and following the tutorial posted https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/advanced-pipeline.html

Trying to set up my first-pipeline.conf where in i need to specify the input , filter and the output configurations

When i specify these configurations , and try 
logsstash -f first-pipeline.conf -configtest i get a RuntimeError

RuntimeError : translation missing : en.logstash.runner.configuration.file-not-found>, class=> RuntimeError : backtrace => ["C:/ELK/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.2-java/lob/logstash/config/loader/rb:58  in 'local_config" and  bunch of other stack trace
Here below is the snip of stack trace
[image]

looks like im missing some files in my logstash installation direcotory..

BTW here is what my first-pipeline.conf file looks like

[image]

Also , i commented out the filter portion of my first-pipeline.conf as was not sure if grok was causing this issue and still the same error is reproducible

Answer (score 0):

The error "io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated" seems a jruby bug:

https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/3550

And It seems to be fixed on version 1.7.24. In Logstash 2.3.2 jruby version is 1.7.23 that the bug opened for. So you can try to download jruby 1.7.25 and replace it with the  one under `vendor/jruby`.

For the other error, you are running Logstast from `bin` folder. Is your configuration (first-pipeline.conf) file actually in that folder? If not specify it from where it is.